# Permissão de câmera no Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-manifest, android-permission

Tenho a seguinte permissão de acesso à câmera e armazenamento no arquivo AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Porém ao instalar o aplicativo no meu Smartphone, a permissão de câmera vem desativada, tenho que entrar nas permissões do aplicativo e ativar manualmente para o aplicativo funcionar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As permissões de armazenamento, aparece uma pergunta ao abrir o aplicativo, se o usuário deseja permitir que o aplicativo salve fotos. Porém a câmera não pergunta. 
O que devo fazer para a pergunta aparecer para permissão da câmera também ?

Comment: Tem que fazer o mesmo que foi feito para a permissão de armazenamento.

Answer (score -1):

A câmera não solicita permissões do usuário. Altere essa permissão no seu AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />
```

Comment: Não pediu a permissão da câmera fazendo deste jeito

Comment: Havia entendido que você já queria que o app estivesse com a permissão garantida ao instalar.

Comment: Márcio, fazendo desse jeito, a permissão da camera ao instalar o app não veio setada como verdadeiro.

Comment: Estranho. Vou dar uma olhada com calma em casa mais tarde. Um app que fiz há pouco tempo declarei desse jeito.