# Android - app para de funcionar quando abro a camera

Tags: java, android, android-camera

tenho um projeto que existe um formulário que o usuário pode tirar uma foto para inserir, isso funcionava mas devido uma atualização do android sempre que clico no botão de tirar foto o app para, alguém sabe o que pode ser?

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: clients.ravero.net.jgpforms, PID: 13356
              android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_20180315_124134_131115397.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
                  at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1799)
                  at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2346)
                  at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:832)
                  at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9514)
                  at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9499)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1644)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5037)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:5023)
                  at android.app.Activity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:7507)
                  at android.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1150)
                  at android.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1139)
                  at clients.ravero.net.jgpforms.fragments.FormFragmentBase.startTakePicture(FormFragmentBase.java:275)
                  at clients.ravero.net.jgpforms.fragments.FormFloraArvoresIsoladasFragment$3.onClick(FormFloraArvoresIsoladasFragment.java:294)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6257)
                  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11149)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23705)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6780)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
```

metodo

```
    @Override
public void startTakePicture(int requestCode) {
    int finalRequestCode = requestCode + REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PICTURE_BASE;
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        try {
            mPhotoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        // Continue only if the file was created
        if (mPhotoFile != null) {
            mPhotoFileUri = Uri.fromFile(mPhotoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mPhotoFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, finalRequestCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Você adicionou permissão no manifest ?

Comment: No emulador acontece o mesma coisa ? LogCat apresenta algum erro ? Seria interessante colocar a versão do android anterior e versão atual.

Comment: Veja se é algo do tipo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203465/permiss%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%A2mera-no-android

Comment: adicionei o manifest e os erros pessoal

Comment: Posta o método que está executando...

Comment: A partir da API 24, o android considera uma falha grave de segurança a exposição de uris que digam respeito a arquivos (file://). Então, sempre que propagar um intent pelo sistema com uma uri desse tipo, receberá uma FileUriExposedException em resposta. A solução é criar um content provider especializado pra essa situação. Ele se chama File Provider. O tenso que ficou chato implementar da nova forma.

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144898/android-camera-intent-fileuriexposedexception-for-sdk-24